# Sonar Maven plugin - fail the build on violation

Tags: java, maven-2, continuous-integration, metrics, sonarqube

Is there a way to configure [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) or the Sonar Maven plugin to make a build fail when a violation of a certain priority (Blocker, Critical) is detected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to define alert thresholds on the number of blocker/critical violations (>0 is your case) in quality profile and install the build breaker plugin (category "Integration" in Update Center of sonar 2.4).

Comment: This is a good solution, but requires root access to sonar server and affects all projects. A less intrusive solution would be to execute a curl statement against sonars quality gate health endpoint, e.g. http://yoursonarserver:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=yourProjectKey